# Support tickets showing on localhost not on webserver

Tags: php, mysql

So I found this simple support ticket php code, and i implemented it on my website.
The manageTickets.php shows me the customers tickets. And I can click the ticket title to navigate to viewticket.php?id="ticketid" It shows it properly on my localhost, like this: http://puu.sh/nwaQy/6eae16d699.png

this is on my actual website: http://puu.sh/nwaZr/0802a282c7.png

So for some reason it doesn't run the php code I think.

All the other php works just fine and it's just on this page.

managetickets.php

```
                                <?php
                            $SQLGetTickets = $odb -> prepare("SELECT users.username,
                                                                    tickets.ticketID,
                                                                    tickets.ticketTitle,
                                                                    (SELECT ticketResponses.time FROM `ticketResponses` WHERE ticketResponses.ticketID = tickets.ticketID ORDER BY ticketResponses.time DESC LIMIT 1) AS lastResponseTime
                                                                FROM `tickets`
                                                                INNER JOIN `users` ON tickets.userID = users.ID
                                                                WHERE
                                                                    tickets.ticketStatus = 1 AND
                                                                    (SELECT ticketResponses.userID FROM `ticketResponses` WHERE ticketResponses.ticketID = tickets.ticketID ORDER BY ticketResponses.time DESC LIMIT 1) = tickets.userID");
                            $SQLGetTickets -> execute();
                            while($getInfo = $SQLGetTickets -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $username = $getInfo['username'];
                                $ticketID = $getInfo['ticketID'];
                                $title = htmlspecialchars($getInfo['ticketTitle']);
                                $lastResponseTime = $getInfo['lastResponseTime'];
                                $responseDate = date('d/m/y H:i', $lastResponseTime);

                                echo '<tr><td>' . $username . '</td><td><a href="viewTicket.php?id=' . $ticketID . '">' . $title . '</a></td><td>' . $responseDate . '</td></tr>';
                            }

                            ?>
```

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the right database? And that there's data there you can access?

Comment: Yeah you can't just upload your localhost files to your webserver. You must update the connection info on your files and make sure there is a database with the same tables on the webserver

Comment: Completely aware of that, its all in one database. As i said, everything else is working properly and it's connected to the database. And the managetickets.php is working just fine on localhost. so i really dont have a clue what might be the problem

Comment: In that case... Check your return values to make sure the queries are working, add in debugging to check the statement is being generated properly, run it directly on your live database, and so on.

Comment: Just ran the query directly on the database and nothing seems wrong with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I spend allot of time trying to figure out what the problem was.
And after some time i decided to purchase another webhosting to see if it was hosting related.
And yes, everything works now since i moved hosting.

Wasn't a coding failure aparently.

Thanks all for your responds!